# Split string with backslash

Tags: javascript, jquery, split

I need to split a string with a backslash.

> I M \ SPLITTING

My expected result :

> [   "I M ",   " SPLITTING" ]

I have tryied the following :

```js
console.log(("I M \ SPLITING").split("\"));
```

```js
console.log(("I M \ SPLITING").split("\\"));
```

Works fine with slash :

```js
console.log(("I M / SPLITING").split("/"));
```

Comment: "\ " is just " " with the space escaped, isn't it?

Comment: There is no backslash in your original string, after complilng

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, your string does not contain backslash, interpreter thinks its a single escape character.
Try this solution

```js
console.log(("I M \\ SPLITING").split("\\"));
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to escape the backslash in your string and in your split parameter, otherwise it will be either

- "\ " => " " (just a space)
- "\" => "(escaped)" (syntax error)

```js
console.log(("I M \\ SPLITING").split("\\"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are correct as per:

```
console.log(("I M \\ SPLITING").split("\\"));
```

However you need to understand escape characters to understand why.

For a quick 101 on Javascript Strings --> https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp

JavaScript uses the \ (backslash) as an escape characters for:

```
\' single quote
\" double quote
\ backslash
\n new line
\r carriage return
\t tab
\b backspace
\f form feed
\v vertical tab (IE < 9 treats '\v' as 'v' instead of a vertical tab ('\x0B'). If cross-browser compatibility is a concern, use \x0B instead of \v.)
\0 null character (U+0000 NULL) (only if the next character is not a decimal digit; else it’s an octal escape sequence)
```

**Note that the \v and \0 escapes are not allowed in JSON strings.**

Answer (score 0):

The most easier way of doing is by converting the given string in raw string where we retrieve the backslash as it is

for above scenario "\b1\c1\d1" into ["","b1","c1","d1"]

```
let a = String.raw`YOUR_STRING`;

let b=a.split("\\");

for eg;

let a =String.raw`\b1\c1\d1`; //Output a ="\b1\c1\d1"

let b = a.split("\\"); // Output b = ["", "b1", "c1", "d1"]
```

This is an alternative approach for it.

Have already tested in chrome console and for more information on String.raw method please refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw